# Proving very basic property of surfaces in $\mathbb{R^3}$

Tags: differential-geometry, surfaces

> Let $X: U \subset \mathbb{R^2} \mapsto\mathbb{R^3}$ be a regular parameterized surface, i.e
>
> a) $X$ is $C^{\infty}$;
> b) The differential of $X$ at any $q \in U$, $dX_q:\mathbb{R^2} \mapsto \mathbb{R^3}$ is injective.
>
> Prove that if $F$ is an invertible, $C^{\infty}$, function, then $\overline{X} = F \circ X$ is also a regular parameterized surface.

I don't know what do here because this looks so obvious that a simple "$\overline{X}$ is the composition of two differentiable and injective linear maps so it satisfies a) and b)" would suffice, but unfortunately I don't trust myself enough to consider the exercise done with just that. So, am I correct here? If not, how do I go about proving it? If it's not what I'm thinking of I'm sure there must be another argument that is probably something just as simple.

Comment: Your argumentation is wrong. Nonetheless, try proving a) and b) for $\bar{X}$: a) is trivial, for b) you need the infamous chain rule

Comment: @b00nheT What is infamous about the chain rule?

Comment: @b00nheT For a), does the argument "$\overline{X}$ is the composition of $C^{\infty}$ linear maps, so it's $C^{\infty}$" hold? And for b), $d\overline{X}_q = dF_q(X) dX_q$, correct? How do I prove this is injective? Also, could you point out the mistake in my earlier argument?

Comment: $X$ and $F$ are just smooth maps, no linearity assumption is present.
b) Yes, that's the chain rule. Now use the info on $F$ and $dX$

Comment: @b00nheT Oh, that's completely right, it was careless of me to think that. One would be tempted to use the argument that $\overline{X}$ is the composition of smooth maps and therefore smooth. Is this correct?

Comment: @b00nheT Well $dX_q$ is injective by definition, and so is $dF_q(X)$. It's tempting to say that this means the product will be invertible, but I'm aware that's not necessarily true. What other info could I use to prove the injectivity?

Answer (score 1):

$\overline{X}$ is clearly differentiable because it's the composition of differentiable maps. Similarly, $d\overline{X}_q = dF_{X(q)}\cdot dX_q$, the composition of injective maps, hence injective, as desired.